# Automator (Or Python?) for Splitting CSV Files by rows

Tags: python, csv, terminal, automator

I want to create a tool to use at work to split large CSV files into Rows using Terminal. I am not a coder so was hoping to use Automator (But somebody said it may be able to be done in Python).

I know the terminal command to split the files at 10000 rows.

```
split -l 10000 example.csv
```

What I would like to do is create an Automator Action I can send to others that will do the following.

1. Ask for the location of the CSV (prefer OS X dialog)
2. Ask for the number of rows to split at (in case they want to change it)
3. Ask for filename
4. Provides `filename-numbers.csv` files

Is this possible? Anybody knows how I would go about doing this in Automator Version 2.7 (428)? Greatly appreciate any assistance with this!